# Selected values from the database doesn't show in the form

Tags: php, mysql, oop

I'm new to PHP OOP, and I have a problem here. I am trying to select users from my database and display it in the form, I don't get any errors, but the users still are not displayed. Could someone help me to solve this problem and tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is my displayusers.php file:

```
<?php
class Display {
private $connection;


public function __construct ($connection) {
    $this->connection = $connection;
}

public function displayUsersValues() {
    $query = "SELECT name, surname, employment_date FROM employee";
    $stmt = $this->connection->dbh->prepare($query);
    $stmt -> execute();
}
}
?>
```

I made the connection in the different file and it is done good, so where is the problem? Thanks for any help guys! Remember, I'm new to this, so just trying to learn...

Comment: In displayUsersValues(), are you actually doing something with the result you get from $stmt->execute() ? The execute() only gets you values from the database, you have to display them yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first, You are not returning anything from *displayUsersValues()*

And probably you want to use PDO::query instead of PDO::execute

Comment: Thank you, just replaced that